# Draw dots on a blank window

Tags: python

I am an artist. I have Python installed. It works. What I am trying to do is to create images on a white screen (window) based on reiterative algorithms. I can't seem to get anything to put dots on a window. If I could just get a bit of python code that, and the library(s) that contain that code, based on an x,y coordinate, that could draw a dot in that window I pretty much could figure out the rest. Also would be nice to vary the color of the dot.
So flow control would look like:

1. Calculate an x,y coordinate (my equations would do that)
2. Specify a dot color (this might always be the same color)
3. Draw the dot at the specified coordinate.
4. Pump the x y answers from 1 above back into equation and calculate a new x,y coordinate.
5. Loop to 2 above a specified number of times.

I can pretty much figure all this out but the "draw the colored dot" is beyond me.

Comment: SO is not a coding service, you should try to solve your problem and if at that moment you have some difficulty then at that time you publish a question detailing the inconvenience. In addition, the task you ask is done by several libraries so you will find multiple answers, also in SO you will find many codes, please perform the search before asking.

Comment: Check out Turtle graphics for Tk here https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.dot

Comment: This is a very broad question (and likely will be closed). You could use one of the many plotting programs to graph your points. For example: matplotlib.

Comment: This may be more adapted than python for what you intend to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vX8wT1G798&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6aFlwukCmDf0-1-uSR7mklK

Comment: If you want to make a GUI program in python for plotting points, you can use Tkinter or pygame module which are really easy to implement.
Have a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `dot()` method in the turtle library that comes with Python is your simplest solution:

```
from random import randint, choice
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

COLORS = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'cyan']

screen = Screen()

width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

for _ in range(randint(10, 100)):
    radius = randint(5, 45)

    x = randint(radius - width//2, width//2 - radius)
    y = randint(radius - height//2, height//2 - radius)

    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.dot(radius * 2, choice(COLORS))

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Turtle also has a `circle()` method but it draws from the edge of a circle (based on a radius instead of a diameter) not the center like the `dot()` method.  One advantage of `circle()` is the outline and fill can be different colors unlike `dot()`.

Comment: Thank you all so very much for all the wonderful options. I believe I will go with the turtle option created by cdlane although the pygame snipit by Eric is very industrious. But a bit beyond my brain. I did come up with an option of my own (you guys will be so proud of me LOL) using Tkinter:

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=900)
canvas.pack()

# loop here
#algorithm here
line = canvas.create_oval(w,x,y,z,fill="red")
#loop

root.mainloop()

I know the above is not actual code but if you put numbers in the wxyz spots it work.